# Removing \r,\n and \ in r string

Tags: r

I have a string in the following format. (I pick it up from a notepad file). I want to get rid of all the \r,\n and . I have tried the following but nothing seems to work. I just get back this exact string. Sometimes with more slashes.

- > gsub('[\r\n]',"",string_x)
- > str_replace_all(string_x,'[\r\n]',"") #using stringr
- > str_replace(string_x,'/[\r\n]/g',"")

  "\r\nvalue = T3M; \r\nstarting = current date - 2M; \r\nForeverTM = current date + 1; \r\nReduceby = MX: \ "DYCOML" on current_date; \r\nexchangeat = 1000*OFL;"

Comment: Post your example data as `dput(string_x)`

Comment: `gsub('[\r\n]',"",string_x)` works for me.

Comment: Try `readLines(textConnection(string_x))`

Comment: sorry for the edit, SO screwed the string even further adding more escapes, so rolled it back to original..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
gsub('[\\r\\n]',"",string_x)
```

Sometimes in Windows you have to escape slashes twice.